# How to increase size of subplots and reduce horizontal spacing?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I would like to have a smaller spacing in the horizontal to be able to increase the size of the supplots, but I don't know how to do that

Here is my code:

```
# DEFINE FIGURE SIZE
fig, axarr = plt.subplots(6,3,figsize=(30,30))

for i in range(6):

    for ii in range(3):
        #IMAGE
        axarr[i,ii].imshow([[1,2],[2,3]])
        # ADDITIONAL 
        axarr[i,ii].axis("off")
        axarr[i,ii].set_title(str(i), color = 'red')


plt.show()
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

I tried to change the figuresize to 150x150, but the result is almost the same (the titles are not visible anymore):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the figure dimensions to have a 6/3 ratio. More generally, if you have Nlines x Ncols subplots, you will want to use figure dimentions with a Nlines/Ncols ratio.

This is because `imshow()` uses [an `'equal'` aspect ratio by default](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect) to ensure that pixels end up square on the screen. That means that the subplots, which were originally created with a rectangular shape with little horizontal spacing, are being resized to have a square shape without changing the dimensions of the figure, leading to large gaps between the subplots. To avoid this problem, choose the size of the figure carefully so that the subplots are already square before the call to `imshow()`.

```
width = 5
fig, axarr = plt.subplots(6,3,figsize=(width,width*6/3))

for i in range(6):

    for ii in range(3):
        #IMAGE
        axarr[i,ii].imshow([[1,2],[2,3]])
        # ADDITIONAL 
        axarr[i,ii].axis("off")
        axarr[i,ii].set_title(str(i), color = 'red')


plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice and helpful answer ! Thank you very much !!

Comment: I prefer the solution listed here, but you can also use the axes_grid1 toolkit: https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/toolkits/axes_grid.html